# How do I create a GUI for already existing data within MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So what I am needing to do is create a GUI for said code given, which is for this case, **Test_01**. I then import another project in this project, which is **Test_02** that contains classes, methods, and everything that I should need to call upon in the web application.

To be able to access the contents of **Test_02**, do I need to create the specific controller(and if so, how can I tell which files I need(there are over 100 choices) in **Test_01** or drag and drop the files into my Models folder and then call on them that way that I know I may need or not need.

Comment: Not sure why we all got down voted, so I'm up voting. The question was a little difficult to understand, but I don't think it deserves a down vote, and the accepted answer certainly doesn't deserve a down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the assembly of `Test_02` in `Test_01` then you can access the classes from `Test_02`

1. Right click `Test_01` project then choose `Add Reference`
2. Choose solution then select `Test_02` from the list.

Don't forget to add using statements in your c# files.

`using Solution.Test_02;`

Comment: +1 - why would someone down vote and accepted answer? It seems perfectly acceptable to me.

Comment: I'm not sure why any answer should be. It was more than I knew before, and which is why I'm asking! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, its rather difficult to understand your question. It sounds incomplete.

It sounds like maybe you have a data model and want to know how to build an application using that model?

You can do this by creating a new project and adding the existing model classes to your project. You can right click the models folder and choose add>existing item.

Let me know if this makes sense or is off target.

Comment: I know. I sat on this for about 15 minutes. 
But yes, your question given for me does sound about right. 
And it makes sense! Thanks!